# "Error : RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was aborted, errno 10053 while pushing code in master "

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my local changes to master repository. Meanwhile it shows me error.

Below is my cmd which I have used.

C:\Users\Jyoti Nagpal\eclipse-workspace\Selenium>git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 130, done.
Counting objects: 100% (130/130), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was aborted, errno 10053
Wfatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (130/130), 13.73 MiB | 6.91 MiB/s, done.
Total 130 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. A question needs to present more context about the issue : what action triggers this error ? What have you tried, or searched ? Also : the error message contains a line which would be good candidates for a google search : `RPC failed:... errno 10053`. Run a search to see if you don't already find an explanation for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the buffer size by using below command:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

If SSL issue persists try the below command:

```
git config http.sslVerify "false"
```